# Is this search page a good candidate for pairwise/allpairs testing?

Tags: testing

I am learning the Combinatorial testing and wondering if the below search page is a good candidate for pairwise or all pair testing. If it is then appreciate suggestions

1. on various classes of values I can use for each of the applicable parameters.
2. Should I include all the fields?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a reasonable chose for the testing you want to do.

You could make life easy on yourself by making the numerical values integers and everything else strings. If you feel like getting fancy, you could use an enumerated type for the states and the consumer/customer radio.  Otherwise use strings and a bool respectively.

If you are just testing it hardly seems necessary to include all the fields, just include as many as you need.  Using all of the data could make for a more robust test, but that's really up to you.